# How to desclare some variables in a datastructure on basis of a flag variable

Tags: c++

I am new in c++.I just got an assignment from my teacher which says:

Consider a library database comprising of students records with the following
attributes:

• Book ID (auto generated ID, e.g. 1240)

• Book Title (maximum of 30 characters)

• Author Name (maximum of 30 characters; consider single/first author only)

• Publisher Name (maximum of 30 characters, e.g. Pearson)

• Year of Edition (e.g., 2000)

**• Status (issued/not issued. Hint: you can use a flag variable for this)
• Date of Issue/Returned (if issued, shows that date of issue; otherwise shows the date of last returned. Format: ddmmyyyy.)**

Your job is to write a C/C++ code to be able to perform the following operations on the library database. You are required to use a single-linked list for this program

Below is what I tried to do with it as per my understanding

```
#include<iostream>

#include<fstream>

#include<conio.h>

#include<stdio.h>

#include<string.h>

using namespace std;

int autoBookID = 0;

struct Librecord{

    int bookID = ++autoBookID; 

    char title[30];

    char authorname[30];

    char publishername[30];

    int yearofedition;

    bool issuedflag = false;

    bool status = issuedflag;

    if(status)

        char dateofIssue[11];

    else

        char dateofreturn[11];

    Librecord *next;

};
```

Below is the error on compiling my code
**17    2   D:\C++ Programs\Assignment#2.cpp    [Error] expected unqualified-id before 'if'**
**19    2   D:\C++ Programs\Assignment#2.cpp    [Error] expected unqualified-id before 'else'**

Any Help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You don't need to declare anything based on the flag, you just need to handle it correctly based on the flag. They're both dates.

Comment: You should *interpret* the date field differently depending on the "issued" status, not have two different date fields. (The description even says that they're the same attribute.)

Comment: Why go to all this trouble just for the syntactic sugar of different names for what is the same variable? Just name it better.

Comment: Just merge `dateofIssue` and `dateofreturn` into one variable called `issue_or_return_date`.

Comment: Now i got it Thanks to all for help

Comment: For the above mentioned question an instruction says that "Assign dynamic memory for an initial list of five books. Initially store data for five
books, using assignment statements" ... I can't understand word dynamically here .... Linked list itself is a dynamic memory allocation... Is this instruction means to declare an dynamic array?